# How can I sort -unique every other line in Linux?

Tags: linux, sorting, sed

I have a FASTA file and I want to get rid of redundancies only for the sequence (even number of lines) not the header.

```
>headerX
**SEQUENCE1**
>headerY
SEQUENCE2
>headerZ
**SEQUENCE1**
```

I want to get rid of the of the identical sequence (SEQUENCE1)

Comment: Your question is very hard for mortals to understand. Could you try to make it clearer to non-FASTA, bio-humans please? Your title mentions *"every other line"* - are you showing us the line that needs changing or the other one? Or is it a trick?

Comment: It's not clear what output you expect. Would you drop both lines `>headerZ` and `**SEQUENCE1**` because sequence1 is already under `>headerX` ? --or-- would you keep `>headerZ`, with no line under it? Please provide a sample output for the sample input.

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'sed' for this,

```
sed -n 2~2p data.fasta  | sort -u
```

This will print all of the even numbered lines in data.fasta and then sort the result to remove duplicates.